# Progress indicator is not working in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a progress indicator in below playground with 2 buttons next and previous
but when I click on next button the value of step changes but the path value doesn't change, can anyone please look and suggest what am I missing.

[Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/aV3iWK5h/4/edit)

Comment: I'm pretty sure people would want you to post some code here, just in case the playground link goes dead...

Answer (score 4):

`lightning-progress-indicator` takes a string for the `current-step`... so all you need to do is call toString() on your current step.

**[Playground link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/aV3iWK5h/34/edit)**

Here:

```
@track progressStep = 1;
@track progressStepString = "1";

nextPage () {
    this.progressStep++;
    this.progressStepString = this.progressStep.toString();
}
prevPage () {
    this.progressStep--;
    this.progressStepString = this.progressStep.toString();
}
```

Comment: Can you please give Playground Link so that we can understand more

Answer (score 2):

Check the Playground [LINK](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/aV3iWK5h/29/edit).

Its working as you want. You needed to iterate `lightning-progress-step` & increment.

Answer (score 2):

This is because current-step takes value as string , hence either iterating or hardcoding value as passing as String will solve the purpose

@Mohit: Thanks but if i case the requirement is to hard code it  we may use following

html

```
<template>

    {step}

    <lightning-progress-indicator current-step={mystep} type="path" variant="base">
        <lightning-progress-step label="Contacted" value="1"></lightning-progress-step>
        <lightning-progress-step label="Open" value="2"></lightning-progress-step>
        <lightning-progress-step label="Unqualified" value="3"></lightning-progress-step>
    </lightning-progress-indicator>

    <lightning-button label={prevLabel} class="slds-float_left slds-p-left_small" onclick={prevPage} icon-name="utility:back"
     variant="brand">
    </lightning-button>

    <lightning-button label={nextLabel} class="slds-float_right slds-p-right_small" onclick={nextPage} variant="brand" icon-position="right"
     icon-name="utility:forward">
    </lightning-button>

</template>
```

js

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {

    @track step = 1;
    @track mystep =1;

    nextPage = () => { this.showSpinner = true; this.step++;this.mystep = this.step.toString(); this.showSpinner = false; }
    prevPage = () => { this.step--;this.mystep = this.step.toString(); }
}
```